# How to format and add columns?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I extract data from SAP R/3 and create Excel reports manually.

I can add columns and use formulas to get required result, you can see in below screen shot. The highlighted yellow columns needs to add and get required result using mentioned formulas.

#### Mat count Daily Report

[image: Mat count Daily Report]

I am working on macros but can't get result.

This Excel sheet has 4 tabs
1. Pivot Table
2. Mat Report- As mentioned above screen as it is
3. Auto/ Non Auto: From Status (Last Column)

I can filter and choose Auto and Non Auto data and create Auto and Non Auto new tab and get data.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
Sub LoadData() ' ' LoadData Macro '

' With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _ "TEXT;C:\Data\data.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$1")) 
.Name = "data" 
.FieldNames = True 
.RowNumbers = False 
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False 
.PreserveFormatting = True 
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False 
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells 
.SavePassword = False 
.SaveData = True 
.AdjustColumnWidth = True 
.RefreshPeriod = 0 
.TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False 
.TextFilePlatform = 437 
.TextFileStartRow = 1 
.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited 
.TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False 
.TextFileTabDelimiter = False 
.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False 
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True 
.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False 
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True 
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False End With

End Sub
```

I am using above code to load data from .csv file which is extracted in C drive location. After that I want to format the Excel sheet to add required column with formula but it does not.

Comment: While it seems that you have been around SO for a while, I would like to remind you that SO is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with their code. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task you wish to achieve.

Comment: At present the code you've added has appeared as an 'answer' to your own question. I have grabbed your code and edited your question to include it within the question to avoid any confusion.  You may also want to delete your answer, also to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I would try another way as VBA, since you are doing a typical ETL task. Use for that the free [Microsoft Add-In Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) (Excel 2010 +). It's very powerful and intuitive. You can extract your data from your csv-File (or even directly from SAP), add the missing columns in order to get a table as source for your pivot-table.